# HTTPS request using Net::HTTP's block form -- is it possible?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, net-http

To do a Net::HTTP https request without the block form you can do this:

```
...
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
...
```

But is there a way to tell Net::HTTP to use https when doing the block form?

```
u = URI.parse(url)
Net::HTTP.start(u.host, u.port) do |http|
  # if I put http.use_ssl = true here, ruby complains that this can't
  # be done becuase the sesion has already started
  resp = http.get(u.request_uri)
end
```

I'm on ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See the documentation for [Net::HTTP.start](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.2/Net/HTTP.start) which takes an optional hash. From the documentation:

> opt sets following values by its accessor. The keys are ca_file, ca_path, cert, cert_store, ciphers, close_on_empty_response, key, open_timeout, read_timeout, ssl_timeout, ssl_version, **use_ssl**, verify_callback, verify_depth and verify_mode. If you set :use_ssl as true, you can use https and default value of verify_mode is set as OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER.

```
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :use_ssl => true)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm on [1.8.7](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.8.7/Net/HTTP.start)

Comment: @John Then you can't do it. Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have method signatures for this. Unfortunately you won't be able to use the block form if you want to set `use_ssl`. You can of course you can patch the 1.9.2 version of start in: https://gist.github.com/2cdc187fa0c7b608fe2c